# Creating and maintaining android libraries

Tags: android, git, gradle, open-source, android-library

I have a module ready to be published onto the maven repo. I've read how to do it and I have made a module of my code as well, but there are some thing I don't get with respect to managing the module to be open sourced and the same module in the main project simlutaneously:

1. How do you create and maintain the library: The library is currently situated in a closed source proprietary project. How do I push this to an open source github repo? Do I initialize a new git repo for the module?
2. If I create a new git repo, how do I maintain it? Since I will be working on, and hence performing edits on the private repo, how do I ensure that the changes reflect in the public repo? Do I copy the changed files to the open source repo?
3. If I keep the open-source repo in my closed-source repo project, where do I add the respective samples for it?

This looks like a solved problem though, but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: It seems like you are asking how to maintain both a private and public repository, is that the essence of your question? Or are you trying to figure out how to make changes to a private repo and then still have that be accessible to others? Your question is not easy to follow.

Comment: My bad, I couldn't figure out better grammar for the same, you're free to edit, the former one is what i'm looking for, how to maintain the public and private repo both, since the code is actually pulled from the private repo, the private repo will always be a few iterations ahead, how do I make them reflect on the public repo as well? And the sample project too, where should I place it?

Comment: I had to do just this for a work project and ended up just maintaining 2 different folders with 2 different git origins: 1 public and 1 private. So as to prevent giving out confidential information, I just update the private and then refactor the code into the public repo while removing any identifying information. I am not sure if there is a more efficient way to do this, but this has worked for me.

Comment: okay, no worries. Let's see if we find an automated solution to this problem.